# Can a permanent resident file I-130 & I-485 for spouse concurrently if final action date is current and spouse lives in the US?

Tags: usa, immigration, family

The Visa bulletin for July 2020 lists the final action date for the F2A category as current. Does that mean my permanent resident spouse and I can file the I-130 and I-485 forms concurrently? I have read contradictory information from various sources so I'd really appreciate answers with references and/or personal experience.
Things to note: I am lawfully present in the United States; I am not from China, India, Mexico, or the Philippines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The I-130 petition and I-485 for Adjustment of Status can be filed concurrently if a visa number is immediately available for the person's category (as determined by [USCIS's Adjustment of Status filing chart](https://www.uscis.gov/green-card/green-card-processes-and-procedures/visa-availability-priority-dates/adjustment-of-status-filing-charts-from-the-visa-bulletin)). See [8 CFR 245.2](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/245.2)(a)(2)(i)(B-C):

> (B) If, at the time of filing, approval of a visa petition filed for
> classification under section 201(b)(2)(A)(i), section 203(a) or
> section 203(b)(1), (2) or (3) of the Act would make a visa immediately
> available to the alien beneficiary, the alien beneficiary's adjustment
> application will be considered properly filed whether submitted
> concurrently with or subsequent to the visa petition, provided that it
> meets the filing requirements contained in parts 103 and 245. For any
> other classification, the alien beneficiary may file the adjustment
> application only after the Service has approved the visa petition.
>
> (C) A visa petition and an adjustment application are concurrently
> filed only if:
>
> (1) The visa petitioner and adjustment applicant each file their
> respective form at the same time, bundled together within a single
> mailer or delivery packet, with the proper filing fees on the same day
> and at the same Service office, or;
>
> [...]

The categories for which concurrent filing are allowed are: the Immediate Relative category (INA 201(b)(2)(A)(i)), the family preference categories F1, F2A, F2B, F3, and F4 (INA 203(a)), and the employment-based categories EB1, EB2, and EB3 (INA 203(b)(1-3)).